# Executing a Python program from crontab

Tags: python, cron

I have created a Python 2.7.3 program on my Raspberry Pi that writes an XML file.  When I run this program using IDLE's `F5` key, it runs and outputs the XML file. When I run the same program using an LXDE terminal at the `pi@raspberry-pi ~ $` prompt by typing `python program_name.py`, it also works as intended and outputs the XML file.

Now I want to refresh the XML file every 15 minutes, and it sounds like I should be able to do this using crontab.

So I started with the command `crontab -e` which opens up the editor (`nano`, in my case). I entered as the last line the following:

```crontab
*/15**** python /home/pi/program_name.py
```

I also tried various variants as follows:

```crontab
*/15**** sudo python /home/pi/program_name.py
```

and:

```crontab
*/15**** python program_name.py
```

When I exit the program I get the error message:

```
"/tmp/crontab.nyQZsu/crontab":23: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The hour, minute, month, and other fields in a `crontab` file are whitespace-separated.  Unless you've got a `cron` variant I haven't seen before, cramming all your fields together into a single blob like "****" is a syntax error.

From the POSIX Programmer's Manual:

> [...] a crontab entry is a text file consisting of lines of six fields each.  The fields shall be separated by <blank>s.

That's what the "bad command errors in crontab file" message is telling you:  The file you fed `crontab` is invalid, so the program refuses to "install" (accept) it.

For comparison, here's the error I got when trying to install a file that included a deliberately bogus line, `***** /bin/echo`:

```
$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXe2lUUa":5: bad hour
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.XXXXe2lUUa
$
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. From any of the examples I saw, I did not pick up on the fact that each of the 6 fields were separated by a blank space. (just realized that I'm not supposed to say "thanks" in these comments!!)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 15 instead of /15

Also, if you want a crontab entry to run as root, it's better to put it in a /etc/cron.d/ file than in root's own user-level crontab.

Comment: What is the benefit of having the crontab entry to run a root?

Comment: A lone `15` in the minutes column would run the script at 15 minutes past each hour, not every 15 minutes.